# PsExec is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that needs to run a script on a remote computer. I'm doing so by using psexec via "Execute windows batch command":

```
C:\PsExec.exe \\computername -u username -p password -accepteula c:\xxx.exe
```

When I run the job I get the following error:

```
c:\PsExec.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

** `PsExec.exe` is located under `c:\`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it located under `C:` on the machine where the command is delegated by jenkins? What is your setup?

Comment: Yes, Psexec is located under C: on the machine (windows) where the command is delegated by Jenkins.

Answer (score 7):

First Define psexec.exe path in environment varaiable "PATH" or else place psexec.exe file in C:\Windows\System32\

And to Download Psexec.exe file
https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is the version of [`PsExec.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx): 32bits or 64bits.

If you have the 32 one on a 64bits machine, that command would not be recognized indeed. `PsExec64.exe` would.

Comment: How your Jenkins slave is running? As a service, with the system account? Or with your account? Maybe there is security access issue. (there should not be a PATH issue as in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35094, since you specify the full path of the executable)

Comment: I'm running Jenkins slave with my account (not as a service).

Comment: @YAM Then try and do a job which only make simple commands (for testing) like: `dir C:\ `, dir and `c:\PsExec.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I can see the age of this question and my answer may not be relevant to this topic since I was technically trying to solve a different problem, but maybe this will help other people who are stuck.

> c:\PsExec.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

I was trying to disable the Maintenance Configurator with PSExec (my problem is the never ending maintenance bug) and kept running into the same error as the OP BUT I got PSexec64 to run this command:

> C:\PsExec64.exe -s schtasks /change /tn >"\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Maintenance Configurator" /DISABLE

BY checking the "Run this program as an administrator" option under the Compatibility settings for "PsExec64.exe"

Don't know if this has solved my problem yet, but I think the OP would have been able to run his process if he had done this. Dear OP did you ever solve that?